# Is an empty StrokeDashArray defined to result in a solid line?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In a WPF view I have a StrokeDashArray property on a Polyline defined by a bound property. Based on the program state (how far zoomed in/out the picture is) I want to draw the Polyline either with a dash pattern, or solid. I noticed through experimentation that if I set the StrokeDashArray property to an empty DoubleCollection, I get a solid line. Is this the accepted way to achieve a solid line? Am I guaranteed to continue to see this behaviour when using future versions of .NET/other relevant software components? I cannot find anything in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokedasharray(v=vs.110).aspx) that addresses this.

Comment: who knows... but what's wrong with `="1 0"` ?

Comment: Nothing, I just didn't think of that because I'm not very smart.

Comment: don't you be that self deprecating! You're awesome! Period.